# What are these two diodes (D1 and D2) used for across a voltage regulator IC?

Tags: power-supply

[image]

Why use these two diodes (D1 and D2) across a voltage regulator?

Comment: Please provide a source for the image

Comment: The clue is the large capacitors C1 and C2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are protection diodes as recommended in the [LM338 datasheet.](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm338.pdf)

From page 15 of the datasheet:

[image]

Notice the red circled text.  Each diode protects the IC from fault current from a specific capacitor.

From page 14:

> When external capacitors are used with any IC regulator it is sometimes necessary to add protection diodes to
> prevent the capacitors from discharging through low current points into the regulator. Most 20-μF capacitors have
> low enough internal series resistance to deliver 20-A spikes when shorted. Although the surge is short, there is enough energy to damage parts of the IC.
>
> When an output capacitor is connected to a regulator and the input is shorted, the output capacitor discharges into the output of the regulator. The discharge current depends on the value of the capacitor, the output voltage
> of the regulator, and the rate of decrease of VIN. In the LM138 this discharge path is through a large junction that is able to sustain 25-A surge with no problem. This is not true of other types of positive regulators. For output
> capacitors of 100 μF or less at output of 15 V or less, there is no need to use diodes.
>
> The bypass capacitor on the adjustment terminal can discharge through a low current junction. Discharge occurs when either the input or output is shorted. Internal to the LM138 is a 50-Ω resistor which limits the peak discharge current. No protection is needed for output voltages of 25-V or less and 10-μF capacitance. Figure 18 shows an LM138 with protection diodes included for use with outputs greater than 25 V and high values of output capacitance.

You only need the protection diodes if the output voltage is over 25V or the capacitor values are more than 10µF.

Comment: let say if both capacitors discharges where will that current goes

Comment: With the diodes, the current will flow back to \$V_{IN}\$.  Without the diodes, the current would flow back into \$V_{OUT}\$ and \$ADJ\$.

Comment: i think you cure my OCD thanks dear sir

Answer (score 3):

They're probably there to prevent damage from reverse voltage in some fault scenario, or even during normal operation.

For instance, if the input voltage Vin were to short to GND, this would put Vout across the LM338 in the reverse direction.  This could also happen during normal turn off operation, because C1 would hold up the output voltage while the input voltage went to zero.

Similarly, C2 would hold up the voltage on the Adj input of the '338.

No, I have not dived into the '338 data sheet to see if these are really required.  But this answer is based on experience with linear regulators many years ago.